# enumerate in reverse order

Tags: python, perl, awk

```
cat dummy_file
    A   ID1  
    A   ID2   
    A   ID3
    B   ID4
    B   ID5
    C   ID6
    C   ID7
    C   ID8
    C   ID9
```

Awk command bellow groups and enumerates `dummy_file` items by the first column.

```
 awk '{count[$1]++}; {print $0"\t"count[$1]}' dummy_file
    A   ID1  1
    A   ID2  2
    A   ID3  3
    B   ID4  1
    B   ID5  2
    C   ID6  1
    C   ID7  2
    C   ID8  3
    C   ID9  4
```

How to reverse enumeration `count[$1]++` (enumerate in reverse order) for the output like this:

```
    A   ID1  3
    A   ID2  2
    A   ID3  1
    B   ID4  2
    B   ID5  1
    C   ID6  4
    C   ID7  3
    C   ID8  2
    C   ID9  1
```

Comment: Really quite difficult, since you don't know how many instances of a given letter there will be. You'll need to do a fair chunk of look ahead. Awk can do it (I think), but it will be messy - I think it would be easier via a perl/python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input is ordered by the first field: this solution uses only a single pass, temporarily storing the data in an array, then printing and clearing the contents when a change of key or end of file is encountered:

```
[rev_enum.awk $] cat reverse_enumerate.awk
#!/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN{idx=1}
NF==2 {
    if(key!=$1){
        print_and_clear();
    }
    data[idx]=$0;
    idx++;
    key=$1;
}
function print_and_clear()
{
    n=length(data);
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        print data[i] " " n-i+1;
    }
    idx=1;
    delete data;
}
END{print_and_clear();}
[rev_enum.awk $] cat dummy_file
    A   ID1
    A   ID2
    A   ID3
    B   ID4
    B   ID5
    C   ID6
    C   ID7
    C   ID8
    C   ID9[rev_enum.awk $]
[rev_enum.awk $] ./reverse_enumerate.awk dummy_file
    A   ID1 3
    A   ID2 2
    A   ID3 1
    B   ID4 2
    B   ID5 1
    C   ID6 4
    C   ID7 3
    C   ID8 2
    C   ID9 1
[rev_enum.awk $]
```

Maybe this is of some use to somebody. :/

Just for completeness, here's a solution that doesn't assume the file is sorted by the first column. Obviously, this buffers the entire file in memory, which could be prohibitive for large files.

```
#!/bin/gawk -f 
BEGIN{idx=1}
NF==2{
    if($1 in data){
    data[$1]=data[$1]","$2;
    }else{
    order[idx++]=$1;
    data[$1]=$2;
    }    
}

END{
    n=length(order);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        m=split(data[order[i]], temp,",");
    for(j=1;j<=m;j++){
        print order[i] " " temp[j]" " m-j+1;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*IF* the input file is indeed ordered on the first column, as you show in your example, and you want the "first-column's index number in decrasing order", then:

```
awk '
   (NR==FNR) { occured[$1]++ ; next ; } 
             {print $0,occured[$1]--; }
    ' dummy_file dummy_file
```

It's a quite common "double loop", ie, we read the file twice, and distinguish the first pass using "NR==FNR".

The above awk program:  1) on the first pass, increment (it's 0 by default) the number of occurence of each things seen on the first column. And skip the rest to go to the next line. 2) on the 2nd pass on the same file : output the line, adding after it the "remaining occurence" of the first column.

This outputs, given the OP's current example file:

```
$ awk '
      (NR==FNR) { occured[$1]++ ; next ; } 
                {print $0,occured[$1]--; }
      ' dummy_file dummy_file

A   ID1 3
A   ID2 2
A   ID3 1
B   ID4 2
B   ID5 1
C   ID6 4
C   ID7 3
C   ID8 2
C   ID9 1
```

The actual presentation of the ouput can be tweaked as we want, to keep/simplify/change the spacing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Same solution as Olivier's, but in Perl. Read the file, splitting each line on tab using the autosplit switch `-a` with the `-F` switch to set the specific delimiter. Store the elements in array `@a`, keep a hash as a counter for the first element. After the file is read through, go through the array, printing the elements back, and also printing the hash counter while decrementing it.

```
perl -F'\t' -anle 'push @a, [ @F ]; $x{$F[0]}++; 
                   END { print join("\t", @$_, $x{$_->[0]}--) for @a }'
```

**Output:**

```
A       ID1     3
A       ID2     2
A       ID3     1
B       ID4     2
B       ID5     1
C       ID6     4
C       ID7     3
C       ID8     2
C       ID9     1
```